# Reason for twisted rotation?

Tags: origin

I have a case, and I want to close its lid.

However, when I set the rotation, the lid doesn't close as I expected, but instead rotates in a weird way, and I don't understand how to change this.

Here is what I'm experiencing. The last image shows the result:

[image]

Thank you for the help.

Comment: are you rotating it by the x axis, or are you just rotating it in orthographic view?

Comment: looks like the black axis is an empty.  Can you select it?  Does it appear in the outliner?

Comment: @RBlong2us Thank you. I have added another screenshot. I hope this gives some more information about it?

Comment: yup.  That's an empty

Comment: so, have you rotated on the x axis?

Comment: To get rid of the empty, either delete it or hide it.

Comment: @RBlong2us I have delete it, but the rotation problem still persists.

Comment: how are you rotating?  What buttons are you pressing?

Comment: I am rotating the upper lid by changing the Transform - Rotation X value (I drag the number).

Comment: perhaps show a screenshot of that?

Comment: try pressing r, x and 90.  make sure the transformation orientation is on Global

Comment: Yes, that does the job.

Comment: Here is a video of what I have tried: https://youtu.be/v4IguuYl6fc

Comment: I need to be able to close the lid using one of the rotation values (like I have shown in the video). I will port the object over to Unity, and in Unity, I have to be able to close it by using one of the rotation values (like I have shown in my video).

Comment: k, hold on.  I'll take a look

Comment: try resetting the Z and Y axis to zero

Comment: How should I do that, please?

Comment: Alright, first get the lid in the upright position, like it was at the beginning.  In the object panel in properties, under transform, do the z and y fields both read zero?

Comment: In the upright position, X is -113, Y=-5.16, Z=-14,1.

Comment: ok, select the lid, and hit ctrl-A and apply rotation.  Then try rotating

Comment: You made it!! In the upright position, I clicked "Applied Rotation and Scale". Then all rotation was at 0. And THEN it worked fine.

Comment: cool!  Mission Accomplished!  Obstacle was Obliterated!

Comment: You could glady make your comment the answer!!! Thank you so much!

Comment: ok, did that.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had not applied the rotation to your object.  Since you had rotation amounts in each axis field, it caused the lid to rotate in the wrong direction when you tried dragging only one field in the properties tab.  It was causing it to rotate on the object's **local** axis.

You can apply the rotation by selecting the object in Object Mode, hitting ctrl-A, and selecting "Apply Rotation."  Now, if you use one of the fields to rotate the object, it will rotate as expected, on the **global** X axis.

As for the axis object that you wanted to get rid of, it turned out to be an empty in your scene, which looks like was the parent of the case objects.  Just delete that if you want, or, if you want to keep it, just hide it.

RBlong2us out!